# how to use IFNull in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have issue that customer_id comes null when there is no data in the table. I know that there is a function IFNULL by using which I can change customer_id null to 0. So here is my query which is not working. checked a lot of related issues solved in the stackover flow but I could not find the solutino for my self if any one can help me with it will be kind of him.
it show me this error

> "message": "Trying to get property of non-object",

**customerController code is**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
         try  {


                   $this->validate($request,[

            'name'=>'required',  
            'contact'=>'required|unique:Customers',  
            // 'contact'=>'required',
            'address'=>'required', 
            'email'=>'required|string|email|max:191|unique:Customers', 


        ]);

         $getId = DB::table('Customers')->select('*', DB::raw('ifnull(id,0)'))->first();

     $getfirst = $getId->id;

        if($getfirst == 0)
        {
            $getfirst = 1;
             $incId = $getfirst;
        } 
        else{
            $incId = $getfirst+1;
        }
        // $lastInsertedId= $Customer->id;

        $Customer= Customer::create([

        'name'=>$request['name']."-". $incId ,
          'contact'=>$request['contact'],
            'address'=>$request['address'],
              'email'=>$request['email']



       ]);
       return response()->json($Customer);
               }

          catch (Exception $e) {
                        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
                    }


    }
```

**customer table is**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
             $table->string('name')->default("مشتری");
              $table->integer('contact')->unique();
              $table->string('address');
              $table->string('email')->unique();
               $table->softDeletes();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: plz post your `customers` table structure

Comment: so do u have primary key in this table?

Comment: yes I do id is set as primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFNULL` is used to check the field is nullable or not.

So it is not used to check a record exist or not.

You can use `empty()` to check the object is exist

```php
$getId = DB::table('Customers')->first();

$getfirst = empty($getId)? 0 : $getId->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$getId = DB::table('Customers')->selectRaw(['*', 'IFNULL(id,0)'])->first();
```

Comment: selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write it as:

```
DB::raw('IFNULL(id, 0)')
```